# Is it proper REST design to send all data for a PUT on the URI?

Tags: rest, uri, put

If I have very simple data to send to the server, is it okay to set up a URI scheme where all of it can be sent on the URI instead of in the body? For example, suppose I'm setting user preferences. I envision something like this:

```
PUT
/preferences/{setting-name}/{setting-value}
```

This allows my client code to be very simple because I can put the entirety of the message in the URI. Is that okay? Or should I be doing something more like:

```
PUT
/preferences/{setting-name}
```

...with the value in the content? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your **first URI** implies that ther is a (sub-)resource at

```
/preferences/{setting-name}/{setting-value}
```

But there is not resource, only a value. Using such an URI is **not RESTful** since it does not address a resource.

Your **second URI** is slightly better since it addresses a subresource `{setting-name}` of the `preferences` resource.

But I would prefer **a third approach**:

```
POST /preferences
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "setting-name": "setting-value",
}
```

to put one preference. Note the usage of `POST` instead of `PUT`. `PUT` is generally interpreted as containing a *complete* representation of the resource in the request body. Such a request should overwrite *all* settings. Using `POST` is generally interpreted as overwriting only the setting specified in the body. Other settings are meant to be unchanged.

**Note:**

What makes me wonder is the front of your URI. Is there really only one set of preferences? Can and should *all* clients access the same set of preferences? If, for example, the preferences are user-based, you should use URIs like

```
/user/{user-id}/preferences/{setting-name}
```

to access the `{setting-name}` preference value of user `{user-id}`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! That makes great sense.

Regarding the URI, my thinking was that all of my API calls happen within the context of a specific user, so I figured there was no need to explicitly name the user each and every time. Is that not kosher?

Comment: What does 'in the context'  mean? How is the user specified?

Comment: The user is identified by presenting a token from a previously completed auth handshake. That token could be presented via a header or a cookie, but it must be in the request or the server will reply with unauthorized. There's no usage mode for this api that makes sense outside the context of a particular user.